# How to Create a Linux VM in Azure Using ARM Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-compute-emulator

Please help me with some reference ARM PowerShell Cmdlets for creating a Linux (Redhat version) VM

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modifying the sample from [New-AzureRmVM documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603754.aspx), the below PowerShell script should do the job (modify parameters as needed) - it will provision a RHEL 7.2 VM. Check for name collisions with your own resources before you run it.

**Please remember that you CANNOT provision pay-as-you-go Red Hat Enterprise Linux VMs on subscriptions that have monetary cap enabled (e.g. free, trial, a subscription with monetary credits ONLY, etc.) because it is a third-party charge in addition to the base compute price. [Read here for more details.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/redhat/redhatenterpriselinux72/)**

For quick create it is recommended to use Azure CLI. This would run on Windows, Mac, Linux. It is as simple as:

```
azure config mode arm
azure group create TestCLIRG EastUS
azure vm quick-create TestCLIRG vm1 EastUS Linux RedHat:RHEL:7.2:latest azureuser
```

or use a template, such as [this one](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-simple-rhel).

If you DO find a need for a quick create in ARM PowerShell, please file an issue on [Azure PowerShell GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell).

PowerShell script is more involved as it controls pretty much every aspect of VM creation:

```
## Global
$ResourceGroupName = "Group1"
$Location = "EastAsia"

## Storage
$StorageName = "storageaccname001"
$StorageType = "Standard_GRS"

## Network
$InterfaceName = "ServerInterface06"
$Subnet1Name = "Subnet1"
$VNetName = "VNet09"
$VNetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/16"
$VNetSubnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/24"

## Compute
$VMName = "rhel-vm"
$VMSize = "Standard_D2"
$OSDiskName = $VMName + "OSDisk"

# Resource Group
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location

# Storage
$StorageAccount = New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $StorageName -Type $StorageType -Location $Location

# Network
$PIp = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name $InterfaceName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -AllocationMethod Dynamic
$SubnetConfig = New-AzureRmVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $Subnet1Name -AddressPrefix $VNetSubnetAddressPrefix
$VNet = New-AzureRmVirtualNetwork -Name $VNetName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -AddressPrefix $VNetAddressPrefix -Subnet $SubnetConfig
$Interface = New-AzureRmNetworkInterface -Name $InterfaceName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -SubnetId $VNet.Subnets[0].Id -PublicIpAddressId $PIp.Id

# Compute

## Setup local VM object
$Credential = Get-Credential
$VirtualMachine = New-AzureRmVMConfig -VMName $VMName -VMSize $VMSize
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMOperatingSystem -VM $VirtualMachine -ComputerName $VMName -Linux -Credential $Credential
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMSourceImage -VM $VirtualMachine -PublisherName "RedHat" -Offer "RHEL" -Skus "7.2" -Version "latest"
$VirtualMachine = Add-AzureRmVMNetworkInterface -VM $VirtualMachine -Id $Interface.Id
$OSDiskUri = $StorageAccount.PrimaryEndpoints.Blob.ToString() + "vhds/" + $OSDiskName + ".vhd"
$VirtualMachine = Set-AzureRmVMOSDisk -VM $VirtualMachine -Name $OSDiskName -VhdUri $OSDiskUri -CreateOption FromImage

## Create the VM in Azure
New-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Location $Location -VM $VirtualMachine
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Boris

Answer (score 0):

You have a complete process to do that with Azure CLI (which is a x-plat command-line tool for Azure). For example using
azure vm quick-create command: The quick-create command deploys a VM with a basic infrastructure surrounding it that you can use to prototype or test a concept very rapidly (you can think of it as the quickest way to a Linux bash shell). https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-quick-create-cli/

You can also create a Linux VM from the ground up using the Azure CLI : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-create-cli-complete/

About the OS :
You can browse the marketplace to find the appropriate OS (redhat in your case)https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-cli-ps-findimage/.

If you use this one https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/redhat/redhatenterpriselinux67/, you will be charged as mentioned: "Use of this Pay-As-You-Go image carries a separate hourly charge that is in addition to Microsoft's Linux VM rates".

But instead of using a marketplace image you can also upload & use your own OS image for the provisionning process.

Comment: Thanks Stephanie i will check the above references.

Comment: Is there no powershell ARM cmdlets for creating linux VM ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ARM template and deploy the template with Powershell.
You can start from this simple linux template & customize it according to your needs https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-simple-linux.

And then use Powershell to deploy it using

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ExampleDeployment -DeploymentDebugLogLevel All -ResourceGroupName ExampleResourceGroup -TemplateFile <PathOrLinkToTemplate>
```

Please follow the complete steps mentioned here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-deploy/#deploy-with-powershell